# How do I select only a column of times (e.g., 10:15, 10:35) using PHP and how can I compare those with the current time?

Tags: php, sql, database, time

So in one table I have a column of time values, just a bunch of time values like 10:15, 10:35, etc. Another column has AM/PM as a text. I'm so confused as to how to do this. How do I take those values and compare it with the current time using PHP? I know you have to do a $sql statement but then what?

Also, if it's easier for any of your answers I can add the AM/PM to the time value column so it would be 10:15 AM, 10:35 AM as a text value instead of just the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

In particular:

```
<?php

$now = time();

$some_time = strtotime('11:20 PM');

if($now > $some_time)
   echo "you are late";
else
   echo "you have time";


?>
```